# What is a domain in relation to AD?

Tags: active-directory

This is a very basic question so please excuse me, but is a domain equivalent to an Active Directory Organisational Unit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No sir.

An AD OU is contained inside the domain.

```
Forest contain Domains
Domains contain Org Units
Org Units contain Objects
```